# Flutter overlay image over listtile title

Tags: flutter

What is the best way to layout an image, title and icon like this
[image: overlayed image]

When using a ListTile with a leading image, title and trailing I get this
[image]

Comment: You can use `Stack` for this purpose. Add two children in it, one will be the image and, add the next two into a row, add them next to the image. Adjust the position of the row with `Padding`.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad you shouldn't use `Padding` to position widgets in a stack; that's what `Positioned` and `Align` are for.

Comment: `Align` will not work in the above case. `Positioned` can be used as well but in my experience, it is not responsive on some screens. That's why I suggested `Padding`. It all depends upon the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my implementation using 'Stack'.
Because there is a fixed size value, I think whether it is best solution.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
        height: 70,
        color: Color(0XFFFFA000),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 5,
                      horizontal: 30,
                    ),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'El ilustre',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white),
                ],
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35.0),
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://i.ibb.co/1vXpqVs/flutter-logo.jpg',
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this answer (with a bit of tweaking to enclose the container with the title in an Expanded widget to expand the black box)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :
with using Stack widget, we first added a `container` with `text` widget and then a `CircleAvatar` widget so that `CircleAvatar` can lay over the text widget.

```
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 300,  //define the size of text widget here
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10),
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, top: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Mr. Bun Burgers',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30,
                  child: Icon(Icons.photo),   // Replace this icon widget with your Image asset widget.
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

output :
[image: output]